# Histogram ylim in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of ages that I am trying to set up in a histogram chart, but my y axis looks really wrong. The command I am using is hist(Data$age, main="Distribution of Age", xlab="Age Brackets", ylab="Absolute Frequency", breaks=10, prob=T)

I tried ylim=c(1, 15) as 1 is my lowest frequency and 15 is my largest, but the axies show up correctly, but then the bars don't show up anymore.

Also is there some documentation repository that would help with the research on these kind of things?

Comment: This is most likely due to your use of `prob=T`. As you are plotting the frequency, you do not need this argument. Remove it and the `ylim` argument should work as specified

Comment: Yes, this is most likely the problem. When you use `prob=T` or `freq=F`, you plot the probabilities, which are always between 0 and 1. So, if you set your ylim to `c(1,15)`, you don't see any bars. Just omit this argument and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try hist(Data[,2]) or something similar. Just change the 2 to reference the correct column of the dataset. Your syntax looks OK. Try

```
help("hist")
```

for the histogram help topic.